# How run instant app on my own server without publishing on play store

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I want create a instant app. But I don't want public my app on play store. How I can run instant app my own server by click on link server then run instant app? Is there any solution?

Comment: Publishing an app and running it on your server have nothing in common.

Comment: I don't know how do it. For instant app we must public on play store.yes?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run an Instant App you have two solutions:

- By running it with Android Studio for the development and test. See the CodeLabs https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-instant-apps/#7
- By publishing it on Play Store. If you do not want to make your app public, you can create testers list. See https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7381861

You can not host your instant app on your own server.